# How to use different config files for different environments in a java maven vaadin project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

I want to setup different build profiles in a vaadin based maven application (war file), which should use different config files, e.g. for database config. The simplest would be to replace the *dev* config file with the *prod* config file.

I tried to achieve this with maven-profiles, I already looked through a lot of solutions, but I don't know how to name my directories according to the profiles, because my properties file is in a different place.

My application uses the standard maven directory layout for java files and resources, but the config files are in some subfolder hierarchy:

```
/myvaadinapp/src/main/resources/xxx/xxx/xxx/myapp/project/xxxx/db/config/config.properties
```

**Question:** Where do I have to create the profiles folder and where do I put the different config files?

My profile config:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these in your pom:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/profiles/${build.profile.id}</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

If you use prod profile, put the prod profile related resource files in src/main/profiles/prod directory and put common resource files for all profiles in src/main/resources directory.